# Symfony2: "Fatal error: Class service..." while trying to include a class as an service in config.yml (TCPDF)

Tags: php, symfony, fatal-error

I'm trying to include an extension of the class TCPDF in Symfony2 (2.1.4-DEV) with service container. For that I edited `symfony/app/config/config.yml` with:

```
services:
  extend_pdf:
    class: Acme\VSBundle\extend_pdf
```

In the file `symfony/src/Acme/VSBundle/extend_pdf.php` I have a dummy-class like:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\VSBundle;

// extend TCPF with custom functions
class extend_pdf extends TCPDF {

}

?>
```

which I load in an Controller like:

```
function testAction() {
    $extendpdf = $this->get('extend_pdf');
    return new Response('success');
}
```

This gives me the fallowing error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Acme\VSBundle\extend_pdf' not found in /home/user/public_html/Acme/Symfony/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 417 Call Stack:...

The cache was empty and I have no idea, why it can't find my class.

Thank you

Comment: What if you clear the cache with `php app/console cache:clear` or manually (by deleting the `app/cache` directory)?

Answer (score 0):

You have an incorrect namespace name: ModurexCRM\VSBundle, please fix the namespace name.